# Execute page-specific javascript code after PJAX success

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, pjax

Here's my conundrum:

My website uses PJAX to load HTML into the '#main' container for each page.

Each page has its own specific javascript file. E.g: 'dashboard.index.js', 'inbox.index.js' and so on. 
Note: All libraries are preloaded on the first load of the page through PreloadJS to avoid javascript compilation overhead.

The first load of the page is perfect, no worries, since it is a normal HTML load.

However if i come back to this page again, PJAX won't reload the javascript file, given it's already in the DOM.

What i tried so far & didn't work perfectly:

1. Place javascript file at the bottom of 'main' container. PJAX transfers it to the 'HEAD' of the DOM and won't load it the second time around.
2. Place in-line scripts in the 'main' container to execute functions of each page. Fails since the code is executed before JS libraries are loaded.
3. Bind 'PJAX success' event and execute function. Unable to determine which function to execute based on current loaded page.

Hence, my question:

Is there any strategy to load specific javascript files associated to each page?

Comment: I've already solved the issue. Will post the answer when stackoverflow allows me to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When loading HTML from pjax, i added a 'data-js' attribute to the div, which contained the name of the function to call upon successfully loading HTML.

Then it was just a matter of using the 'pjax:success' event to call the function.

Comment: I would advise to use pjax:end instead

Comment: I use `end` events as well now, when i discovered that pjax didn't execute the scripts on `window.onpopstate`. @Ronald thanks for the tip anyways

Comment: Hello @Mysteryos. I am facing the same issue and would like to load page specific JS. You're saying that you added a data-js attribute to the div, is it the fragment div? I have this: http://pastebin.com/1iCPn40u so it's the .content which should have the data-js attribute? And did you then inside data-js have "dashboard.index.js" so on pjax:end, it performs jQuery getScript( $(this).attr('data-js') ) to load the script? Hope you can help me out!

Comment: Normally, you have an app.js, which you load on every page. It will contain all the logic for loading your page-specific coding: http://pastebin.com/FN2AvBXq

Comment: Hi again Mysteryos. I found out that on the page that are being loaded we can just have scrip tags with type="text/javascript" and these will then be loaded ? If you know this, is there any reason why you chose your own solution?

Comment: @Mysteryos could you provide your project here as an example of your findings above. I have the same problem but it loads up my javascript but never displays it on the page. When moving to another page it still has the same html/javascript as if it was the first page, etc etc

Comment: @StealthRT Here you go: https://gist.github.com/shift-keshav-pudaruth/48357c6ae58ccd646ec7a56cda6ad4c5