# Scripts won't load when using pjax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pjax

I'm using **pjax** with **ASP-MVC-5**, everything works find, but when I load a view using pjax ('a' link click) it won't load scripts.What's the Problem ?
Pjax Registration:

I tried both :

```
    $(document).on("click", "a", function (event) {
        $.pjax.click(event, '#pjaxContainer')
    });
```

and

```
$(document).pjax('a', '#pjaxContainer');
```

but when a page load using pjax, the scripts in the view won't load.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/froala_editor.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    alert("SCript won't fire");
</script>
```

If I refresh the page, Scripts will load correctly, but using pjax, No

**Edit**

If the pages don't load the scripts and I refresh the page using F5, all scripts in pages that already didn't work, will load correctly,

Comment: Does [Execute page-specific javascript code after PJAX success](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24990201/1115360) help?

Comment: Thanks @AndrewMorton ; I don't know why, but even 'pjax:success' won't fire when these pages load in container

Comment: Is your jQuery 1.8.x or higher? Have you tried `$(document).on('pjax:end', function() {`?

Comment: @PHearst; My jquery is 1.10.2 and if my scripts inside the page loaded then alert(); would showed to user. but +1 for **pjax:end**

Comment: Have you tried disabling froala editor?

Comment: Any errors on console log after you load the page ?

Comment: @PHearst ; I have some other pages without that editor, but same problem, If I could I would share the source

Comment: @Kesty, Actually no; if I reload whole page again using F5, all scripts will work correctly, but when using pjax, some sometimes doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

HTML can be loaded either by using innerHTML, or by DOM manipulation. In both cases, if the HTML contains `<script>` tags, they will not be interpreted.

You can however go through the `<script>` tags inside the Ajaxed HTML content, and `eval()` it, if you really need to.

If you use this type of `<script src="http://site/script.js"></script>` script tag, however, it will be interpreted.